# Q.all on partial success

Tags: node.js, q

I just can't seem to find the right way to phrase this for a Google search.

What happens (in node.js) when I use `q.all` and only one or two fail. I need to enter the `.then(` for all the successful instances that I used promises for. The ones that fail do not matter to me.

Is this functionality possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`q.allSettled`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#user-content-promiseallsettled). From the wiki:

> This method is often used in its static form on arrays of promises, in
>   order to execute a number of operations concurrently and be notified
>   when they all finish, regardless of success or failure.